# Drush Open-Source License

Tags: drush

What open-source license is Drush licensed under?

I've checked GitHub including the README (https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/README.md) and it isn't stated anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [last version of Drush](https://drupal.org/node/97249/release) on drupal.org has a GPL v2 license in it.  The license itself is not in the repository.  Modules and themes on drupal.org automagically get LICENSE.txt added by the packaging script (the automated process that creates the tarballs and zips from central git repo).

This means that drush is technically still GPL v2, even though it doesn't have an explicit license in it.  There is [talk about relicensing drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/319), though.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the pull request.  The latest versions of Drush on drupal.org are older versions, for example the 6.0 versions are RC and beta versions.  _The Drush project has moved to Github.. Please see our 6.0.0 release there._

Comment: @Jesse Yeah, they moved to GitHub last summer.  Those versions are GPL, so the GitHub version is, too.  Since the LICENSE.txt wasn't actually in the repo, it didn't carry over.

Comment: Moshe Weitzman commented on Pull Request #319 (https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/319) that the license info is in ccomposer.json (https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/composer.json). `"license": "GPL-2.0+"`